# How do i know the order of the reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

$$\ce{2N2O5 ↔ 2N2O4 + O2}$$ is this reaction first order or second order ? And why ?
I know first order is when duplicating the concetration the velocity duplicates too, and secod order reaction is of order n if, when doubling the concentration, the speed increase by $\pu{2^n}$. For this cases i need the velocitys and concentrations but i only have the initial concetration and 5 hal life times

[image: Temperature x half life time]
$$\ce{N2O5}= 2,4 mols_0$$
I dont know what to do, cuz to know, would have to have this data . Am i wrong ?

Comment: Temperature dependence is not useful here. You would need at least 2  timed data for the same temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Order is an experimental data. It is never possible to derive the order of a reaction from its chemical equation. The order has to be determined by measuring the rate of a chemical reaction (in $\pu{mol/s}$, or in $\pu{mol L^{-1} s^{-1}}$) , and plotting a function of this rate vs. time. If the logarithm of the rate decreases linearly with time, the order is $1$. If the reciprocal of the rate increases linearly with time, the order is $2$. This is not dependent on the chemical equation of the reaction. In both cases, the slope of the line is the rate constant, $\pu{k_{1}}$ or $\pu{k_{2}}$.

This is what you should have to do with your experimental results about the decomposition of $\ce{N2O5}$. But here all you know about this reaction is its half-life. And this parameter (half-life) is a characteristics and a constant of the first-order reactions. So from this very property, you can state that the reaction is first order, without doing any calculations.

As the half-life is known at different temperatures, it probably means that, in a second time, you would have to calculate the activation energy of the reaction.

Comment: But have half life for second-order reactions. $$t_1/2\frac{1}{K*[A]_0}$$